# How is pressure distributed in the combustion chamber of a rocket engine?

Tags: engines, combustion, thermodynamics

How, if at all, does the pressure of the combusting fluid change within a combustion chamber from the injector to the choke? Is it monotonically decreasing in pressure as you go from the injector to the nozzle (which makes sense, given that the fluid is clearly flowing that way)?

Even if so, how uniform is the pressure within the chamber, provided it's properly baffled & there's no combustion instabilities to consider? Is it sufficiently uniform to consider that the fluid is at constant pressure during the entire combustion?

Comment: More than a few Master's Theses could be written on this general topic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This paper [CFD SIMULATION OF A LIQUID ROCKET PROPELLANT (LH2 /LOx) COMBUSTION CHAMBER](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255710939_CFD_SIMULATION_OF_A_LIQUID_ROCKET_PROPELLANT_LH_2_LOx_COMBUSTION_CHAMBER) claims that the chamber properties are essentially constant until the constriction starts towards the throat.

[image]

Comment: Nice to see the CFD simulation confirming my expectation of a constant pressure throughout the chamber.

Comment: 300 m/s [injection velocity](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35113/21562) they say?